# Limit the number of clients on a port using iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, network-security

I realize you can limit the number of tcp connections to a port using iptables. Is there a way to limit the number of unique machines connecting to the port? I do not want to limit a specific ip address, but rather the total number of clients on the port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question has been already answered here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/371763/limit-maximum-incoming-connections-to-a-port-using-iptables

You could use **iptables** using **--connlimit**. It makes no sense to repeat the answer here, since you'll find the answer in the link above. I hope that answers your question.

**UPDATE:**

In this case you can use the **iplimit** module from **iptables**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -dport 80 -m iplimit --iplimit-above 10 -J REJECT
```

This will reject connections on port 80 if there are 10 ip addreses connected. 10 ip addresses will translate in 10 unique ip addresses.

Comment: No because I am talking about unique machines not just connections

Comment: Unique machines should translate in unique ip adresses unless you have machines behind nat/masquera and accessing it with the same ip address. If that's the case I really dont know if iptables is the solution

Comment: Ok thanks I guess the question is how to limit the number of ip addresses on the port because a single ip could have multiple connections. So filtering by connections would not work.

Comment: I have updated my answer and provided additional information